# How to output value into HTML from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I just need a hand with how I can output the array that is randomized into my html to be shown.

What I am trying to do is have my page randomize when clicked from an array of file locations. 
once the location is selected from the randomize then it will be injected into the html and display the video

Here is the code I have so far

```
var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/1.mp4'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'videos/1.webm'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/2.mp4'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'videos/2.webm'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'videos/3.mp4'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'videos/3.webm'}],
];

$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random()*videos.length);
        $(this).video('<source src="'+video[randomIndex]+'" />');       
    });
});

var video = videos[randomIndex];
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="click">
            <section> 
                <div>
                    <video loop autoplay>
                      <source src="videos/1.mpg" type="video/ogg">
                      <source src="videos/1.webm" type="video/mp4">
                      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
                    </video>
                </div>  
        </section>
</a>
```

Pretty sure it is a very easy solution but I am still learning JavaScript and not too sure of the syntax or how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did not get your question. If you want to set html of tag in js then use document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML = yourHTML;

Comment: use something like this `$(this).find('video').append('<source src="'+video[randomIndex]+'" />'); ` instead of `$(this).video('<source src="'+video[randomIndex]+'" />'); `